# Importing a local JS module when running k6 via Docker

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, k6

I'm using the k6 Docker image to run load tests. I have a library file and a test script file in the same directory.

But when I try to open the module file, I get this error:

```
time="2017-10-12T06:59:58Z" level=error msg="GoError: open /library.js: no such file or directory
    at native
    at -:55:95(51)
```

The command given was: `docker run -i loadimpact/k6:latest run -i 1 - <test.js`

In my test.js script, the import statement looks like this:

`import {fn} from "./library.js";`

Comment: You starting a question and in 1 second you also have the correct answer for it? Are you collecting badges?

Comment: No :)  It is not too uncommon practise to add FAQ questions and answers to Stackoverflow. In fact, if you've ever asked a question you'll notice here is even a checkbox that allows you to respond to your own question when asking it. See this link for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133522/encyclopedia-stack-exchange-vs-commercial-products

Answer (score 1):

The Docker container does not have access to your working directory on the host machine. You need to mount it inside the Docker container. Try this:

`docker run -i -v $(pwd):/mnt loadimpact/k6:latest run - <test.js`

You'll need to change the import statement also, so it says:

`import {fn} from "/mnt/library.js";`

..and, of course, library.js has to be in your current working directory when you run the docker command.

(Note that you don't need to add `-i 1` when executing k6, 1 iteration is the default)

And finally, if I were you, I'd probably also skip the piping of test.js to stdin, given that you're mounting a directory anyway. You can do:
`docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt loadimpact/k6:latest run /mnt/test.js`

This means that you're starting a Docker container where your current working directory on the host machine will be mounted on /mnt (in the Docker container), then you tell k6 to execute "test.js" residing in /mnt (which is your current WD on the host) and test.js imports a .js file also located in /mnt (current WD on the host). So all files should be in your working directory.